# isset function for li tag

Tags: php

My coding is like

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION["usr"]))
{
    ?>
    <ul id="top_nav">
        <li ><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <?php
}
else
{
    echo '<ul id="top_nav">';
    echo '<li id="logout"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>';
    echo '<li><a href="#">' . $_SESSION["usr"] . '</a></li> </ul>';
}
?>
```

In php I want to destroy session when user click on logout(which I have used li).
so I want to check using `isset` function.
or any other method then let me know.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to unset session var use `unset($_SESSION['usr'],$usr);`. Both vars are needed to workaround with `register_global` issue. Your code have to be kind of this

```
<?php 
if ($_GET['logout']=='1') unset($_SESSION['usr'],$usr);
if(!isset($_SESSION["usr"])){?>
  <ul id="top_nav">
      <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
  </ul>
<?php }else{ ?>
  <ul id="top_nav">
      <li id="logout"><a href="?logout=1">Logout</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><?=$_SESSION["usr"];?></a></li>
  </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks coramba. i got what i want .Thanks a lot.